# Android Toolbar make icon overlapp into area below

Tags: android, icons, toolbar, android-toolbar

For my app I want to have the same behavior of the `icon` in the `toolbar` as seen in the picture. My guess is they made a `white square around the icon` and then set a `paddingTop` on the icon or maybe `resized` the icon?
How can I do this to only the icon? I already made some mods in my style.xml to the text in the toolbar.
Would this be the right place?[image]

Comment: You can create your own toolbar from zero